# silverlight navigation animation is not smooth

Tags: performance, silverlight, animation, user-controls, silverlight-4.0

I am using a navigation frame in silverlight 4.

I am using slide in animation when navigation the user-controls. the animation and the user-control loads at the same time so the animation is not smooth, it lags for a second and loads the UI and then starts the animation.so the performance was not good.  I tried using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method, but no change in the performance. Is there any other way to handle the animation and the UI loading at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it never disappeared completely but moving code out of your Constructors (View and Model) and into the `UserControl_Loaded` event, and the respective model loaded event does help.